# Do Optaplanner Joiners work on LocalDateTime?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm a little confused with Optaplanner Joiners and data types. Can someone clarify what data types Joiners work on?

Specifically - will they work on LocalDateTime:

```
   ...
   Joiners.lessThanOrEqual( (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime() )
   ...
```

where getStartTime() will return a LocalDateTime

of is this a case where a filter is required?

Answer (score 1):

OptaPlanner Joiners supports LocalDateTime.

`LocalDateTime` implements `equals()` and `hashcode()`, so `Joiners.equal()` works even if they are not the same instance but represent the same datetime.

`LocalDateTime` implements `Comparable`, so `Joiners.lessThanOrEqual()` works as expected.

There's even `Joiners.overlapping()` to efficiently detect entities that overlap fully or partially in time. **Because your model has `getStartTime()` and you're trying to use `lessThan*`, you'll need `overlapping()` semantics.**

Note that the `Collectors` have some `java.time` specific methods like `sumDuration()`. But for `Joiners`, the general purpose ones are enough.

Comment: I was expecting

```Joiners.greaterThan( Lesson::getLevel ),
Joiners.lessThanOrEqual( (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime() )```

gives any unique pair with the level higher and the lesson starts earlier to penalize.

However I have to do this:

```Joiners.filtering( (l1, l2) -> !l1.getLevel().equals(l2.getLevel()) )
.filter( (l1, l2) -> {
  Boolean l1After = l1.getTimeslot().getStartTime().isAfter(l2.getTimeslot().getStartTime());
})
return (l1After && l1.getLevel() < l2.getLevel()) || (!l1After && l1.getLevel() > l2.getLevel());```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: "I was expecting Joiners.greaterThan( Lesson::getLevel ), Joiners.lessThanOrEqual( (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime() ) gives any *unique pair* with the level higher and the lesson starts earlier to penalize. " That is true, unless you're using forEach/fromUniquePair() which auto adds a lessThan(getId()), then you'll get less.